# Why can't I concatenate the JSON?

Tags: java, json, apache-poi

I need to concatenate all BasicDBObject in BasicDBList . Every time the loop runs, my BasicDBObject contains only **ONE** json element and exit my BasicDBList contains nothing. 
 Why does this happen? Put the `dbLinha.clear()` to avoid duplicate but evaluating the code each time the loop runs BasicDBList contains a duplicate!

```
public BasicDBList readMetadados(Planilha planilha) {
        List<String> cabecalho = new ArrayList<>();
        int linhaReferencia = 0;
        BasicDBObject dbLinha = new BasicDBObject();
        BasicDBList listLinha = new BasicDBList();

        try {
            InputStream planilhaFile = new FileInputStream(FileUtils.getFile(UPLOAD_PATH, planilha.getPath()));
            Sheet linhaInicial = new XSSFWorkbook(planilhaFile).getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = linhaInicial.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    try {
                        if (cell.getCellType() != 3) {

                            if (cell.getCellType() == 1) {
                                if ("Veículo".equals(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
                                    linhaReferencia = cell.getRow().getRowNum();
                                    cabecalho.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                        cabecalho.add(cellIterator.next().getStringCellValue());
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (linhaReferencia != 0) {
                                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                        dbLinha.append(cabecalho.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getCellFormula());
                                        break;
                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                        dbLinha.append(cabecalho.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                                        break;
                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                        dbLinha.append(cabecalho.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        dbLinha.append(cabecalho.get(cell.getColumnIndex()), cell.getStringCellValue());
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        Log.info(this, "Erro ao obter valor da linha [{}] e coluna [{}]", cell.getRow().getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
                    }
                }
                if (!dbLinha.isEmpty()) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < cabecalho.size(); i++){
                       if(!dbLinha.containsKey(cabecalho.get(i))){
                           dbLinha.append(cabecalho.get(i), " ");
                       }
                    }
                   listLinha.add(dbLinha);
                   dbLinha.clear();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.error(this, "Erro ao processar planilha: Planilha não encontrada.", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.error(this, "Erro ao processar planilha.", e);
        }
        System.out.println(listLinha.toString());
        return listLinha;
    }
```

Output

```
[ { } , { } , { } , { } , { } , { }]
```

The content of BasicDBList the first time you run is correct, the second time is starting to duplicate and replace with added anteriormentes.

The value of BasicDBList the first time you run the loop ("if (!dbLinha.isEmpty())")
[image]

Second time 
[image]

Comment: It would really help if you could distill this into a *short* but *complete* program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. The main problem is to concatenate all JSONs in "listLinha"

Comment: You still haven't provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save objects by using `clear` and using the same object (`dbLinha`) over and over again. That won't work.

When you add an object to a list, it adds *a reference* to that object, not a *copy* of that object to the list. So basically, what you add the first time is a reference to the `dbLinha` object, and now you have the first item in the list pointing to the same object that `dbLinha` is set to.

Then you call `dbLinha.clear()`.

This means that the reference stored in your list, being the same, will now show an empty object. Then you read another line into the same object, add another **reference** to it to the list, and then clear it again.

Your list gets filled with references to the one, single, object that you are re-using. Here is a demonstration of what is happening:

[image: Demonstration of the process]

If you want to retain your objects, you have to use `new`, not `clear`. You have to create a new object to store the next bit of data, because adding to the list does not create a copy, just a reference. So you basically have to let the reference you added point to the old object, and start with a new one.

Comment: Wow amazing response. I really thought there was a copy in the list.